# PowerShell variables from csv

Tags: powershell

I have a problem with using the variables in my script coming from a csv file. Everytinme the text UNC is found, I want to do something. And when the text UNC is not found, I want to do something else. This is great for running a script locally or on the remote server.

**Script**

```
$File = (Import-Csv -Path S:\Input\Auto_Clean.csv | Select-String -NotMatch "#")

Foreach ($Item in $File) {
    If ( $SERVER -eq "UNC" ) { 
        Write-Host "UNC: $SERVER, $PATH, $OlderThanDays" } 
        else {
        Write-Host "Not UNC: $SERVER, $PATH, $OlderThanDays"}
}
```

**CSV-file**

```
# Input file:
SERVER, PATH, OlderThanDays
Server1, E:\Share\Dir1, 10
Server2, F:\Share\Dir2, 5
UNC, \\Domain\Share\Dir1, 30
```

**Desired result in cosole**

```
Not UNC: Server1, E:\Share\Dir1, 10
Not UNC: Server2, F:\Share\Dir2, 5
UNC: UNC, \\Domain\Share\Dir1, 30
```

The output of `Write-Host $File`is correctly displaying the labels/variants:

```
Write-Host $File
@{SERVER=UNC; PATH=\\domain\Share\Dir1; OlderThanDays=10}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
Import-Csv -Path "S:\Input\Auto_Clean.csv" | % {
    if ($_.Server -eq "UNC")
    {
        Write-Host "UNC: $($_.Server), $($_.Path), $($_.OlderThanDays)" 
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "Not UNC: $($_.Server), $($_.Path), $($_.OlderThanDays)"
    }
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
Not UNC: Server1, E:\Share\Dir1, 10
Not UNC: Server2, F:\Share\Dir2, 5
UNC: UNC, \\Domain\Share\Dir1, 30
```

If you want to ignore lines starting with # you can use the following:

```
(Get-Content "S:\Input\Auto_Clean.csv") -notmatch '^#' | ConvertFrom-CSV | % {
    if ($_.Server -eq "UNC")
    {
        Write-Host "UNC: $($_.Server), $($_.Path), $($_.OlderThanDays)" 
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "Not UNC: $($_.Server), $($_.Path), $($_.OlderThanDays)"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Martin, I just tried it but it's always displaying 'Not UNC: ..' lines and the 'UNC one' line is displayed as 'Not UNC:...' too. At least it does display something this time :) Isn't there an option to use the format `Foreach`without piping?

Comment: Are you sure your CSV matches what you have posted, I have updated my answer with the output that I see?

Comment: Very odd, but it is indeed working now. I copied it again properly this time. Thank you very much Martin. Still figuring out how to have it in variable through the For each loop instead of piping.

Comment: I see now that I had my filtering in place to remove lines starting with `#`as in `Select-String -NotMatch "#"`. That's why my code was not working..

Comment: Yes that's right, Select-String will return a Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo object, I think you were expecting something different.  You don't need the notmatch as the import-csv will do that for you.

Comment: Yup, that was the problem. But when I want to comment something out in my CSV file with the `#`it's not possible, because it's still getting picked up.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example for filtering out lines starting with #.

Comment: Awesome! I've just also found another way of doing this:
`$File = (Import-Csv -Path S:\Input\Auto_Clean.csv | where { $_.Server -NotMatch "#" } )`I guess both ways are the same. Thank you again Martin, really appreciate it.